# multi-table SELECT from mysql database (return multiple items in single field)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some serious help. Here's the thing...
Assume I have a 'users' table with fields(userId, name). Now I need to grab multiple items of info from other table relating to this user. Some of the items are similar so need to be bundled together.

Now I also have several other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE app.phones (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userId` INT NOT NULL ,
`phone` VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.emails (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userId` INT NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.contact_methods (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userId` INT NOT NULL ,
`method` ENUM( 'phone', 'email' ) NOT NULL,
`methodId` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.groups (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`groupName` VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.users_groups (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userId` INT NOT NULL ,
`groupId` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

As you might guess, each user can have multiple emails, phones and be part of multiple groups. How would I display a table like below using all the tables above?

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+
|name     |phones       |emails             |groups        |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+
|John Doe |123-555-0101,|johndoe@mail.com,  |group1,group2,|
|         |123-555-0909 |johndoe2@mail.com  |group3        |
+---------+-------------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

**UPDATE:** Emails and Phones should not be taken immediately from their tables. The table `contact_methods` contains entries which reference those tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for size

```
SELECT u.name, ph.phone, em.email, gr.groupName 
FROM users AS u, phones AS ph, emails AS em, groups AS gr 
WHERE (u.id = ph.userId) 
    AND (u.id = em.userId) 
    AND (u.id = gr.userId) 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Or to concatenate the values to get one row (thanks @chris-morgan):

```
SELECT u.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ph.phone SEPARATOR ','), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(em.email SEPARATOR ','), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(gr.groupName SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM users AS u, phones AS ph, emails AS em, groups AS gr 
WHERE (u.id = ph.userId) 
    AND (u.id = em.userId) 
    AND (u.id = gr.userId) 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the asked question.  He wants one row per name, with concatenated phone, email, and group lists.

Comment: Thanks for this but, in addition to Chris' note, your query doesn't use the table contact_methods.

Comment: +1 answered asked question.  @Chad, your question doesn't specify how to use `contact_methods`.

Comment: @Chad, as Chris said; how would you like to display `contact_methods `?

Comment: Sorry, you are both right, I didn't. 
What I would like to do is, instead of getting the emails and phones for a user directly from the phones and emails table, I would like to first get the user's entries from the contact_methods table. So in my example, it is assumed that John Doe has four entries in the contact_methods table. Two for the email and two for the phones.

Comment: I'm actually going to rethink my database design and decide if I need that contact_methods table or not. If I do, I will have to return to SO for help. For now, I'll take your answer. Thank you.